# Passing arguments of getline() from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-warnings, getline

I know the following warnings are my fault, but I need a bit of help working out what I did wrong. I'm getting: "passing argument 1 of ‘getline’ from incompatible pointer type", and the same thing for argument 2.

Here is my call to getline():

```
getline(&line.buf, &maxSz, stdin)
```

Here are the relevant argument declarations:

```
line_t line;
int maxSz = 1000;
```

and

```
typedef struct line_t {
  char buf[1000];
  int lineLength;   
  int wordCount;
  int index;
} line_t;
```

I believed the issue was that I was taking the address of what were meant to be pointers, but upon testing out a few different calls to getline, I am yet to find a solution. I definitely think argument 2 is the fact that maxSz is not a pointer.

```
while (-1 != (line.lineLength = getline((char**) &line.buf, &maxSz, stdin))) {
        printf("buf is %s\n",line.buf);
```

Why is the above giving me an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About problem with second argument: `&maxSz` of `getline()` you are passing to is of type `int *` but function `getline()` expects second argument of type `size_t *`.
Change the declaration

```
int maxSz = 1000;
```

to

```
size_t maxSz = 1000;
```

About first agrument: I recommend you to replace `char buf[1000];` by `char * buf;`. It is better way to read line when you don't know it's length. But don't forget to initialize it (i.e. add `buf = 0;` before calling of `getline()`). If you read description of `getline()` function you will find, that second parameter is not input. Your `maxSz` doesn't limit maximal length of the string (in this variable you can find number of characters read, including the delimiter character, but not including the terminating null byte ('\0')). Try to compile and analyze [typical example](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed it for argument 2. I'll have a google to make sure I understand size_t properly. Do you know how to fix it for argument 1?

Comment: Thank you so much. That got rid of it! If I later want to print line.buf (just for reference, I am hoping that this will be an entire line of stdin), what format descriptor do I use? I've been trying %s, but that is giving me the following: "format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[1000]’"

Comment: Thank you so much. That's absolutely amazing. May I ask just one more thing? I've edited the question to add some code at the very bottom. It's stuck printing the same line over and over. Would you be able to help me figure out why this is?

Comment: Oh! Don't worry! The infinite loop is somewhere else. My bad! Anyway, thank you heaps for your help and persistence (since I am still getting the hang of this). You've been brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using `fgets` instead of `getline`, e.g.

```
while ( fgets(line.buf, maxSz, stdin) != NULL ) 
{ 
    // do something with the line
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between fgets and getline? I've been using getline because I later reference line length (which I can quite easily get from getline), and found that achieving the same thing with fgets was difficult

Comment: @user4062632 -- `getline` expects the address of a pointer to a char. Your code isn't set up to do that.  To find the length of the line, you want `line.lineLength = strlen(line.buf);`

Comment: Would line.lineLength just give me 1000 though, as I've set the size of line.buf to be 1000?

Comment: No, strings in C are terminated with a NUL character, also written as `'\0'`. Both `getline` and `fgets` put a NUL at the end of the string, so that `strlen` can determine the length of the string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
getline(&line.buf, &sizeof(maxSz), stdin)
```

Comment: This gave me: "error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand" for the second argument, and "passing argument 1 of ‘getline’ from incompatible pointer type" for the first, but thank you for your suggestion